# What is meant for Vanila magento 1 codebase?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento2-migration-tool, code

I am trying to migrate from magento 1 to magento 2 and I have seen on magento website there is a tool for that which is code migration toolkit here's link for the same https://github.com/magento/code-migration.

[image]

In the prerequisite directories section it is saying about **vanila magento 1.x code base**. **I don't have any idea what is meaning of vanila codebase.** Please guys help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In english, `Vanilla` can be used to describe the standard version of a software.

In this case, it describes the standard Magento 1 codebase, the folder where the Magento 1 code sits.

Comment: Is it Mage folder @Raphael ?

Comment: @Ramkishan no it's the folder that contains your Magento 1 installation

Answer (score 8):

Vanilla = unmodified, without any extensions